# If M is free with a finite basis then every basis of M over R is finite and has the same number of elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Stuck on a proof in  my lecture notes.

**Proposition:**
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module. If $M$ is free with a finite basis then every basis of $M$ over $R$ is finite and has the same number of elements.

**Proof:** Let $N \subset R$ be a maximal ideal, and consider the $R$-submodule of $M$ given by $NM:=\{am|a\in N, m\in M\}$. The quotient module $M/NM$ is naturally an $R$-module but because $N\subset Ann_R(M/NM)$,
we deduce that $M/NM$ is naturally an $R/N$-module. Note that because $N$ is maximal, $R/N$ is a field, hence $M/NM$ is actually a $R/N$-vector space.

Let $\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subset M$ be a basis. Note that this implies that $NM=\{a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n|a_i\in M\}$. This
gives rise to the subset $\{[x_1],...,[x_n]\}\subset M/NM$. We claim that this is a basis for $M/NM$ as a $R/N$-vector space.

For $r\in R$ we denote by $\overline{r}$ its image in $R/N$. Suppose that

$\overline{r_1}[x_1]+...+\overline{r_n}[x_n]=[0]$

in $M/NM$ for suitable $r_i\in R$. Since

$\overline{r_1}[x_1]+...+\overline{r_n}[x_n]=[r_1x_1+...+r_nx_n]\in M/NM$

I understand everything up to this point $\overline{r_1}[x_1]+...+\overline{r_n}[x_n]=[r_1x_1+...+r_nx_n]$, but I just can't figure how the $\overline{r_i}'s$ have disappeared on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Note that zero of $M/NM$ is $NM$. Now some corrections:
 replace $"∈"$ in the last formula with "$+$" and delet "$M/$".
Add another row: $[r_1x_1+...+r_nx_n]+NM =NM$ so $[r_1x_1+...+r_nx_n]∈M/NM.$
I used the fact that if for some $m∈M$, $m+NM=0$ in $M/NM$ then $m∈NM$.
So nothing disappeared.you onley wrote $\overline{m}$ for $m+NM$